# Simple population distribution after n generations

Tags: probability

I have a population of 100 individuals (at generation 0). Each of them will generate 0, 1 or 2 heirs in the next generation with equal probability (1/3). So the number of individuals in the next generation (generation 1) is a random variable $X_1$ with $E[X_1]$ = 100 and $Var(X_1) = \frac{200}{3}$ and is approximately normally distributed (because of the central limit theorem). Moreover if we name $X_i$ the population at generation $i$, then $E[X_i] = 100$. My question is: is there a formula for $Var(X_i)$? More generally how is $X_i$ distributed?

According to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74406/variance-of-sum-of-random-number-of-random-variables-cambridge-university-works) $Var(X_2)$ can be computed using the law of total variance ($X_2$ is basically the sum of a random number of iid random variables with distribution $\mathcal{U}[0,2]$).

EDIT: Found that $Var(X_i) = \frac{200}{3}i$ so the variance grows linearly with the number of generations, but still haven't found the general distribution of $X_i$.